# (Python 3.4 Tkinter) IntVar / StringVar Issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Big problem with StringVar()s and IntVar()s. This code gives errors instead of working correctly.

```
x = IntVar()
Radiobutton(root, variable=x, value=1).pack()
Radiobutton(root, variable=x, value=2).pack()

if x == 1:
    do something
elif x == 2:
    do something else
```

I've even put a  `print(x)` and it returns `PY_VAR0`. How to turn `IntVar` into `int`, without breaking it's dynamic response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the value of `x` you must do `x.get()`:

```
if x.get() == 1:
    ...
```